# Haskell. getting same neighbors

Tags: haskell

I'm the cs student who recently started to learn Haskell.
I tried my best to find the way to interpret in Haskell but I couldn't yet. I need help. Here's the explanation. There are three types of content.

```
type Coord = (Int, Int)

-- Type-definition of a Cell: it is just a coordinate and an optional 
AgentType.
-- Note: the agent type is optional and is Nothing in case the cell is 
empty.

type Cell = (Coord, Maybe AgentType)

-- data definition for the agent types
  data AgentType 
    = Red       -- ^ Red agent
    | Green     -- ^ Green agent
    | Blue      -- ^ Blue agent
    deriving (Eq, Show) -- Needed to compare for equality, otherwise would need to implement by ourself
```

Each cell has either a content( can be red, green or blue) or empty. I'm trying to find the neighbours who have the same content from every side including diagonal ways which is 8 in total. If 40% of the cell neighbours are the same as the cell, return true.

```
-- Returns True if an agent on a given cell is happy or not
isHappy :: Double  -- ^ The satisfaction factor
    -> [Cell]  -- ^ All cells
    -> Cell    -- ^ The cell with the agent
    -> Bool    -- ^ True in case the agent is happy, False otherwise

isHappy ratio cs c
    | ratio < 0.4 = False
    | otherwise = True
    where
    moore = [(x-1,y-1),(x-1,y),(x-1,y+1),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1),(x+1,y),(x+1,y-1),(x,y-1)]
    -- here is where I got stuck
```

I made a 'moore' list which contains all direction, but I'm not sure how to compare 'the Cell' to 'neighbours [Cell]'.
My thought is following in another programming language,

```
if (TheCell[X-1,Y] == TheCell)){
    stack ++;
    }
 ...
 ...
 ratio = stack / len(8);
```

I've been searching how to interpreted in Haskell but couldn't find it yet. Maybe my thinking process is wrong. Please help me in any way

Comment: The input format appears to contain only a list of cells ie. a 1D array, not a 2D matrix. You need to say where `x` and `y` are coming from (probably by matching on parameter `c`). You haven't given the definition of `Cell`. The calculation of `ratio` can be expressed as a `fold`. Can you write a function to do that given some list of numbers? Then, how will you generate that list from cell coordinates?

Comment: -- Type-definition of a Cell: it is just a coordinate and an optional AgentType.
-- Note: the agent type is optional and is Nothing in case the cell is empty.
type Cell = (Coord, Maybe AgentType)

Comment: @ATayler Thank you for the advice. I feel like I need to try to understand the whole thing more because since I get even more confused about your advice. Thanks though

Comment: type Coord = (Int, Int)

Comment: Is the grid infinite? In which case the input list of cells is just the non-empty ones?

Comment: @ATayler oh, I got what you mean. so I should first change the moore list .. hmm

Comment: it has boundaries . worldSize :: (Int, Int)
worldSize = (20, 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data Cell = Cell Coord (Maybe AgentType)

inBounds :: Coord -> Bool
inBounds (x,y) = 0 <= x && x <= fst worldSize
              && 0 <= y && y <= snd worldSize

isHappy cs (Cell (x,y) a) = ratioSameNeighbours >= 0.4
    where neighbourCoords = filter inBounds [(x-1,y-1),(x-1,y),(x-1,y+1),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1),(x+1,y),(x+1,y-1),(x,y-1)]
          sameNeighbours = filter ((\(Cell p ma) -> p `elem` neighbourCoords && ma == a) cs
          ratioSameNeighbours = fromIntegral (length sameNeighbours) / fromIntegral (length neighbours)
```

What you've said is still a bit underspecified, (eg. can an empty cell ever be happy?) but this is a start. If the input cell array is supposed to be 2D (rather than a "sparse" representation ie. 1D list of only the non-empty cells) then `ratio` has to be a bit different.

Comment: Your original post is supposed to contain everything needed to answer the question. Please edit it if there's more information you wish to provide.

Comment: `isHappy cs (Cell (x, y) a) = ratio >= 0.4 where …`, and I think you need a `fromIntegral` for the `length` results since `Int` is not `Fractional`.

Comment: @JonPurdy imo the first change hurt readability but is more acceptable with better variable names. added the `fromIntegral`s.